# Unity banner ad admob v5.3.0 not showing

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, google-mobile-ads

My banner ad is not showing

using GoogleMobileAds v 5.3.0

Google AdMob Enabeled is checked and i put my app ID

my game is live on google play i used this code to show the add (from youtube),
when i run the game in the editor i get this in console

Dummy.ctor /
Dummy Initialize/
Dummy.ctor/
Dummy CreateBannerView/
Dummy ShowBannerView /

```
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

//Banner ad
  public class Addload : MonoBehaviour
 {
private string banner = "my ad ID";
private BannerView bannerad;

private void Start()
{
    MobileAds.Initialize(InitializationStatus => { } );

    RequestBanner();


}

private void RequestBanner ()
{

    

    bannerad = new BannerView(banner, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

    bannerad.Show();


}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you actually forget to load the ad. See: [Banner Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/banner)

```
bannerad = new BannerView(banner, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);

// Create an empty ad request.
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

// Load the banner with the request.
this.bannerView.LoadAd(request);
```

Comment: do i keep the "  bannerad.Show(); "  ?